# Adding View doesn't Appear

Tags: android, view, checkbox, handler, addition

I am trying to add checkboxs to a view that I have on my layout. The problem is that is not showing, but I know that is being added because of getChildCount() at parent view returns a new more item..

I am doing this inside an handler, because this method is called inside a Thread.

```
protected void addDeviceToList(final String name, final ConnectSend cs) {

        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(ConnectSend.this, "A: " + listOfPersons.getChildCount()+ " Vou adicionar um!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(cs);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams fieldparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
                checkbox.setTextAppearance(cs, android.R.attr.textAppearanceMedium);
                checkbox.setText(name);
                checkbox.setLayoutParams(fieldparams);
                listOfPersons.addView(checkbox);

                Toast.makeText(ConnectSend.this, "D: " + listOfPersons.getChildCount()+ " adicionei ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

Thanks alot in advance ;)

Answer (score 1):

try using `checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`

Comment: When you add views programatically they are set visible by default.

Comment: Guys thanks for your replys, but the problem was another thing.. it was my bad. The LinearLayout "listOfPersons" were not showing any contents because of another LinearLayout was above it, with android_above tag at XML I fixed it. thanks ;)